# Subscript spacing in equation

Tags: math-mode, spacing, subscripts

I have a document, where I want to use `$\tau_{ff}$`. If this is rendered it looks like a space is inserted between the two f's. `$\tau_{rl}$` looks fine ...

Where does this additional space come from and how can I avoid it being inserted?

(Miktex 2.9 on windows, if this is relevant).

Comment: If the subscript is an abbreviation, it should be set in upright type: `$\tau_{\mathrm{ff}}$`

Comment: I have `$\tau_f` and `$\tau_{ff}`, where both are abbreviations - (ff is a special kind of f). Would you then propose to set the single f upright as well?

Comment: Yes; textual abbreviations in subscripts should be upright; variable names are in italics.

Comment: @egreg Usually I think you would want to use the same upright type that the surrounding text uses. So would it be better to generally use `\textnormal`, rather than `\mathrm`? I saw this idea proposed proposed [here](http://stefaanlippens.net/textnormal).

Comment: @Cerran I usually propose `\textnormal` or `\mathrm`. With `\mathrm` you have to watch for spaces.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Math fonts do not make ff into a ligature the way text fonts do as it may sometimes obscure the meaning of two separate identifiers juxtaposed,

[image]

```
$\tau_{ff}$ $\tau_{f\!f}$ $\tau_{\mathit{ff}}$
```

If the meaning of your subscript is some kind of invisible product of two `f` then use one of the first two, or some other negative space other than `\!` to taste. If on the other hand it is a multi-letter identifier with name `ff` then it is more appropriate to use a text font, as in the third example where the text italic font is used in math mode via `\mathit` and there `ff` produces a single ff ligature glyph.